# Calculate the total number of integer solutions?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + 3x_4 = 71$$

where $x_i \geq 1$

That means I really have:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + 3x_4= 68$$

But now I need to solve for all the values that $3x_4$ can take. 68 does not evenly divide into 3, the closest whole number is 22.

---

Does this mean my solution would be:

$$\sum_{x_4=0}^{22} \binom{70-3x_4}{2}$$

I posted a question similar to this, where it was instead $2x_4$, so the sum in that case was upto 34. (68/2). I'm not sure about this case though.

Comment: It shoud be ${70-3x_4\choose 2}$

Comment: You can get a closed form for this if you review the proof of the hockey stick identity, use induction and seperate into residue of the largest element mod 3.

Comment: Can you link me to the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) method, the solution is:

$$\sum_{x_4=1}^{22}{71-3x_4-1\choose 3-1}=\sum_{x_4=1}^{22}{70-3x_4\choose 2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{x_4=1}^{22}(70-3x_4)(69-3x_4)\\=53130-\frac{417}{2}\sum_{x_4=1}^{22}x_4+\frac{9}{2}\sum_{x_4=1}^{22}x_4^2=17457$$

Comment: Yes, thanks ... by the way, how are you factoring this?

Comment: ${n \choose 2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, then I expand the polynomial, and it's a linear combination in $\sum x_4$ and $\sum x_4^2$